# getting 404 error while registering attaching event in bissubscrible

Tags: jenkins, tfs, continuous-integration

I am attaching a `bissubriscrible` event to trigger each check-in event. But when I try to run the command using `bissubiscrible` tool, I get an error 404.

Its server is using "NT AUTH\Network Service" for authentication.

[image: prompt with 404 error]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `localhost`, you can try with the **tfs server name** or **IP address**.